# Entity framework - 'update from database' not adding table

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I am trying to add new table to an existing model. There are no errors, but the table is not adding to the model. Please let me know, if I am missing anything here.

Steps - 
 1. Right click on the model and click 'update from database'
 2. in the update wizard - choose the table to be added
 3. click finish

Thanks,
Arthi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinstalling EF 6 tools fixed the problem

https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=40762